# Uploadify & ASP.NET Error Handling #2038

Tags: asp.net, uploadify, swfupload

I'm using Uploadify within my ASP.NET 4 project. I'm using an HttpHandler to receive the posted file and process it into a directory. The upload is working fine. However, I wanted to handle any errors I could within my HttpHandler, and I am finding it impossible.

I have the processing of the file wrapped in a try catch, but I am never able to return an error message. I always receive the IO Error: Error #2038

```
try
{
    UploadFiles(context.Request.Files);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

Is it not possible to return custom errors back to the client when using SWFUpload/Uploadify?

Answer (score 0):

Take alook at here

[uploadify error handling](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploaderror/)

> 'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
>               alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
>           }

Comment: I reviewed the documentation for Uploadify, and I have already implemented that event handler. It doesn't appear to ever fire though, I am only getting the IO Error: Error #2038.

Comment: and last one http://forums.asp.net/t/1688871.aspx?Error+2038+IO+error+When+Implementing+Uploadify+in+asp+net+site

Comment: Again, thanks for the effort. I've visited those posts prior to posting here and did not see how they applied. I am dealing with ASP.Net, not php. Also, my upload works! I am just trying to determine how to pass an error to the client if it doesn't.